# Selenium In C# - Reusing Exisiting chrome drivers

Tags: c#, selenium

In my project i'm openning multiple chrome drivers and after it's done i want to reuse them to do more tasks. I'm using C#

Answer (score 0):

Create a list, and each time you open a browser - add it to the list.

```
List<WebDriver> browsers = new List<WebDriver>;
// after creating a new browser do this:
browsers.add(browser);
// later do this
browsers[2] = // code for page 2;
browsers[3] = // code for page 3;
// Close all the browsers at once:
driver.quit();
```